# Why is RegExr.com showing different results to what I am getting?

Tags: python, regex

I am working with a propietary dataset and I am testing a regex pattern to find addresses in a corpus of text.

In order to find addresses I've been using the following structure for address searches:

> Building Number : e.g. Unit 502 
> Street Type: e.g. Park Way 
> City/Town: e.g. Birmingham 
> County: e.g. West Midlands 
> Postcode: e.g. B42 7NR

N.B. these are UK addresses

Using RegExr.com I've tested various patterns and got this and implemented it in code like as follows:

```py
def parse_results(string):
    space = r"([\s\t]{0,5})"
    building_type = r"(([Uu]nit|[Ss]tudio|[Ff]lat)?)"
    street_type = (r"((\d+)(\&|\-)*(\d*)(\w*)(\w*)(\s*)(\w*)(\s*)(\w*)(\s*)"
                   r"([Ee]nd|[Gg]reen|[Cc]auseway|[Cc]heapside|[Cc]rescent|"
                   r"[Ss]treet|[Ll]ane|[Ww]alk|[Rr]oad|[Aa]venue|[Dd]rive|"
                   r"[Pp]ark|[Ww]ay|[Pp]lace|[Pp]arade|[Ii]ndustrial"
                   r"[Ee]state|[Tt]rading [Ee]state|[Hh]ouse|[Gg]reen))")
    line_1 = r"(\w*)"
    line_2 = r"(\w*)"
    line_3 = r"(\w*)"
    line_4 = r"(\w*)"
    line_5 = r"(\w*)"
    postcode = r"(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]?[A-Z0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][A-Z]{2}))"
    pattern = re.compile(rf"({building_type}{space}{street_type}{space}"
                         rf"{line_1}{space}{line_2}{space}{line_3}{space}"
                         rf"{line_4}{space}{line_5}{space}{postcode})")
    try:
        matches = pattern.finditer(string)
        for match in matches:
            address = re.sub(r"\s+", r" ", match.group(1))
        return address
    except Exception as e:
        return (f"Error looking for address, exception {e}")
```

Despite showing on RegExr.com that it should pick up certain addresses, it misses certain ones. Examples include:

- 6B Winterstroke Road Weston-Super-Mare Avon BS23 3YT
- 4 Armstrong Place Milton Keynes Buckinhamshire MK8 0AU
- Unit 11 Buttlands Industrial Estates Totnes Road Ipplepen Newton Abbot Devon TQ12 5UE

I don't know if there is something Pythonic happening that I'm not sure about. Any ideas on this would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `address` is re-written in a loop. You return the last match. You probably want to declare `address` as a list and `.append()` to it. Or use a list comprehension.

Comment: Your first non-match is caused by `\w` not matching a `-`. The second seems to work ok. The third non-match is caused by `[Ii]ndustrial[Ee]state` missing a space in the middle, but when you fix that, you get catastrophic backtracking, probably due to the large number of optional capture groups

Comment: Thanks for this. So what is a good solution to avoid catastrophic backtracking given what I have? Could you give an example?